# Where can I find rubies for enchanting?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I thought I'd start enchanting some stuff, starting with the Blunderbuss for my Cipher. I have the necessary level to enchant it to Exceptional, but I'm missing some required ingredients:

[image]

I have everything but the two rubies, and no idea where to get them. The merchant for crafting stuff in my Stronghold doesn't have them.

Where can I get some rubies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One good source would be Curnd, shady jewel merchant in Ondra's Gift:

[image]

He possesses almost all (if not all) of this games jewels in quantity of 5. Restockable supply (though I do not yet know when does the stock refresh). Rubies you're looking for are worth 1275 gp each.

He is however picky, and requires some persuasion to allow you to browse his wares (Might 15 I belive). Or possibly selling him Blacksmiths Supplies connected with Gilded Vale quest.

It is also worth noting that Curnd only appears at night.