# Where are the ingredient to enchant exceptional items?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I would like to enchant my items as exceptional but it requires some rare ingredients ? Can they be bought somewhere or how to find them ?

Comment: Only adding this as a comment since it less than a third of the answer: Vithrak Brains can be found in the Stronghold curio shop once you have built it.

Comment: Vithraks can also be found in Endless Paths in their alive form, ready to be killed. And http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212176/where-can-i-find-rubies-for-enchanting provides another third of the answer.